# Add tcpsvd to busybox when build toolchain

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, buildroot, toolchain

When I build toolchain to embedded linux I build busybox too.

How can I add `tcpsvd` to my busybox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented in the Buildroot user manual, [Chapter 7. Configuration of other components](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_configuration_of_other_components): use `make busybox-menuconfig` to enter the Busybox configuration menu, then go under `Networking Utilities` and enable `tcpsvd`.

Section [9.4. Storing the configuration of other components](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#customize-store-package-config) of the manual documents how to make your custom configuration permanent.

Comment: thank you, can you please tell me how do I add to this toolchain, `ltrace` and `gdb-server`?

Comment: `ltrace` is not provided by busybox. Look for it in the Buildroot menu (`make menuconfig` is your friend). `gdb-server` is more complex but the manual has an explanation for it. Yes, you really should read the manual.

Comment: I realy search but didn't find how to get ltrace with `make menuconfig ` Is there any way to search there? and not search manualy?

Comment: It shouldn't be super had to find by navigating the menu, it's a target package and it's used for debugging. But you can also search: every menu in  `menuconfig`  has a help text, just under the title line.

Comment: Oh, and the Buildroot manual explains that too: "in menuconfig, the search tool is called by pressing /" (http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#configure)